How to hide a JEditorPane's caret?
I have a JEditorPane which sometimes should not show its caret.
In the code below I tried to toggle the caret visibility depending on a JCheckBox state - but in vain.
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class HideCaretInEditorPane extends JFrame {

  public HideCaretInEditorPane() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(230, 200);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JEditorPane pane = new JEditorPane("text/html",
    "To see the caret's visiblity, the EditorPane must have the focus.");
    pane.setEditable(false);
    pane.getCaret().setVisible(false);
    add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel p= new JPanel();
    JCheckBox cbVisible= new JCheckBox("Visible");
    cbVisible.addActionListener(e -> {
//    Failing attempt to toggle caret visibility.
      boolean b= !pane.getCaret().isVisible();
      System.out.println(b); // Always true, i. e. the caret is erroneously reported as not visible.
//      pane.getCaret().setVisible(b);
      pane.getCaret().setVisible(false); // No effect.
      pane.requestFocusInWindow();
    });
/*
    cbVisible.addActionListener(e -> {
//    Toggle both editability and caret visibility. -> Caret blinks when editable,
//    but is always visible.
      boolean b= !pane.isEditable();
      System.out.println(b);
      pane.setEditable(b);
      pane.getCaret().setVisible(b);
      pane.requestFocusInWindow();
    });
*/
/*
//  Workaround
    cbVisible.addActionListener(e -> {
      Color color= pane.getCaretColor();
      pane.setCaretColor(color==Color.WHITE ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
      pane.requestFocusInWindow();
    });
*/
    p.add(cbVisible);
    add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setVisible(true);
  }
 
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(HideCaretInEditorPane::new);
  }

}

A second attempt and a workaround is found as comment.
Still I would like to know, why my first attempt in using setVisible(...) on the caret is not working.
Win10, java 22

Change the setEditable boolean to false when you want the caret to disappear.

@Gilbert Le Blanc - I have two pane.setEditable(...) in my code. The 1st has "false" as a constant parameter, the 2nd has the toggling variable "b" in my 2nd attempt. Trying to follow your suggestion I activated the 2nd attempt and made "b" a class variable. But the caret never disappears. Could you post the snippet which worked for you, please?

I created a simple GUI to illustrate removing a JEditorPane caret.

When the GUI first comes up, the editor pane is editable.  The caret blinks at the end of the text.  After you press the button at the bottom, the editor pane is not editable.  There is no caret.
After you press the button at the bottom again, the editor pane is again editable.  However, there is no caret.  You have to left-click on the editor somewhere to make the caret appear again.
Here's the complete runnable code.
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.Caret;

public class JEditorPaneExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JEditorPaneExample());
    }

    private JEditorPane editorPane;

    private JPanel editorPanel;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JEditorPane Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        editorPanel = createEditorPanel();
        frame.add(editorPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createEditorPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        editorPane = new JEditorPane();
        editorPane.setText("This is a test of the emergency broadcast system.");
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(editorPane);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));

        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        JButton button = new JButton("Not Editable");
        panel.add(button);

        button.addActionListener(event -> setEditorState(event));

        return panel;
    }

    public void setEditorState(ActionEvent event) {
        JButton button = (JButton) event.getSource();
        String text = button.getText();
        if (text.equals("Not Editable")) {
            editorPane.setEditable(false);
            button.setText("Editable");
        } else {
            editorPane.setEditable(true);
            button.setText("Not Editable");
        }
    }

}


Thank you, Gilbert, for the example; now I see what you mean. You influence the caret by changing the editability of the EditorPane. As for the caret this is, however, not a definite/final state; for even when the pane is non-editable, you can make the caret reappear by a simple click. I want the caret's visibility independent of editable state, thus dependent only on my code and not modifiable by the user (unless the code permits).

Looking into the sources of DefaultCaret, one finds that the caret is always painted, even when using damage(Rectangle r). To me it looks as if the contract of the Caret Interface is not fulfilled.
So the easiest way to hide the caret is indeed to change its colour to the background of the JEditorPane. This idea is from MadProgrammer at How to get textfield that updates from listener in Java Swing for Hangman game?
